# Which classes can and cannot be serialized using Binaryformatter

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

There are several [articles](https://www.google.com/search?ei=vRitW5nUCaGt_QbB1q64Cg&q=c%23%20when%20a%20class%20can%20be%20serialized%20using%20binaryformatter&oq=c%23%20when%20a%20class%20can%20be%20serialized%20using%20binaryfor&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i21j33i160l3.13711.42891..44826...5.0..0.151.1914.32j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10j33i22i29i30.nY2ukyvQuyM) online on how to `serialize` a class using [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Can someone explain which types of classed can be serialized and which types cannot using Binaryformatter?

Comment: As far as I know, any class that is decorated with [Serializable] can be serialized. Of course any class referenced from the current class via public properties must also have the attribute applied.

Answer (score 1):

Generally classes marked with the [Serializable] attribute can be serialized with that Binary Formatter. That includes the classes your write yourself. You will need to add that attribute to your own classes. 
One more thing that the comment above reminded me about: You have to put that [Serializable] attribute on your class and any other class that it uses too. So if your class A is serializable, and it uses class B -- then class B needs to be serializable too.

There is a gotcha though: .net standard or .net Core does not support the BinaryFormatter. 
We only got it to work for types that come from the .NET Framework (for windows desktop).